# javascript: check if iframe url is same domain or something external

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I know I can't access data in an iframe which displays a page from another domain. That's perfectly fine, but I'd like to detect, whether the iframe currently shows a page from my domain or something external.

My first attempt would be to try to access

```
$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document
```

wrapped in `try {} catch {}`, and if an error is thrown it means I can't access it, and therefore the iframe page must be external. 
This sounds like a perfect solution, but the thing is safari posts a "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL" message to the javascript console. 
This is not just ugly, but may cause other or future browsers to display explicit security warnings to the user?

Comment: Your solution seems perfectly valid. Pay no attention to the noise from Safari, which is not visible to end-users.

Comment: Incidentally, you’ll also get warnings in the Safari console when you load www.apple.com. Warnings are not generally anything to worry about (although they can be very annoying and, IMHO, should be something that the console should allow you to filter.)

Comment: thanx, i'll leave it as that for now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)?

If there is no response, it is an external domain.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="300" id='iframe'>
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

wouldn't it be just that simple:

```
var iframeEl = document.getElementById('iframe')
var src = iframeEl.src;
```

and then use it to compare to your domain?

Comment: `src` always returns the initial value, but the iframe page will definitely change due to following links / submitting a form within the iframe

Comment: Should still be enough to know whether it is on the same domain, unless you somehow end up on your own domain by following some link inside the iframe, the initial value should do, no? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not check if the href attribute from the iframe is the same as your domain?

```
parent.frames[1].location.href;
```

Comment: This will cause a security error. You cannot even check for the existence of the keys 'href' or 'origin' or anything else that's in the location object :(